# Postgresql LEFT JOIN json_agg() ignore/remove NULL

Tags: postgresql

I am using a LEFT JOIN there will be cases where there is no right-table match therefore empty (null) values are substituted for the right-table columns. As a result I am getting `[null]` as one of the JSON aggregates.

```
SELECT C.id, C.name, json_agg(E) AS emails FROM contacts C
LEFT JOIN emails E ON C.id = E.user_id
GROUP BY C.id;
```

Postgres 9.3 creates output for example

```
  id  |  name  |  emails
-----------------------------------------------------------
   1  |  Ryan  |  [{"id":3,"user_id":1,"email":"hello@world.com"},{"id":4,"user_id":1,"email":"again@awesome.com"}]
   2  |  Nick  |  [null]
```

How can I ignore/remove `null` so I have an empty JSON array `[]` when the right-table column is null?

Answer (score 197):

In 9.4 you can use coalesce and an aggregate filter expression.

```
SELECT C.id, C.name, 
  COALESCE(json_agg(E) FILTER (WHERE E.user_id IS NOT NULL), '[]') AS emails 
FROM contacts C
LEFT JOIN emails E ON C.id = E.user_id
GROUP BY C.id, C.name
ORDER BY C.id;
```

The filter expression prevents the aggregate from processing the rows that are null because the left join condition is not met, so you end up with a database null instead of the json [null]. Once you have a database null, then you can use coalesce as usual.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Comment: This is great! It also works for `json_object_agg`:

`COALESCE(json_object_agg(prop.key, prop.value) FILTER (WHERE prop.key IS NOT NULL), '{}')::json`

Comment: 8 years later with Postgresql 12.x, this solved my problem perfecly.

Answer (score 31):

something like this, may be?

```
select
    c.id, c.name,
    case when count(e) = 0 then '[]' else json_agg(e) end as emails
from contacts as c
    left outer join emails as e on c.id = e.user_id
group by c.id
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5eb65/7)</kbd>**

you also can group before join (I'd prefer this version, it's a bit more clear):

```
select
    c.id, c.name,
    coalesce(e.emails, '[]') as emails
from contacts as c
    left outer join (
        select e.user_id, json_agg(e) as emails from emails as e group by e.user_id
    ) as e on e.user_id = c.id
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5eb65/42)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks Roman, I was actually wondering if a conditional would be the best idea. Is this faster than using a `COALESCE` or something similar?

The query doesn't _have_ to be a `LEFT JOIN` just as long as the emails table is turned into JSON as a `emails` field.

Comment: can't think about faster way to do this, you can try use inner join and then union with contacts where contact.id not exists in emails, but I doubt this will be faster..

Answer (score 9):

If this is actually a PostgreSQL bug, I hope it's been fixed in 9.4. Very annoying.

```
SELECT C.id, C.name, 
  COALESCE(NULLIF(json_agg(E)::TEXT, '[null]'), '[]')::JSON AS emails 
FROM contacts C
LEFT JOIN emails E ON C.id = E.user_id
GROUP BY C.id;
```

I personally don't do the COALESCE bit, just return the NULL. Your call.

Comment: I'm on 12, still getting nulls on left join, are you sure it is a bug?

Comment: I did say "if this is a bug". And after 5 years, it's definitely not a bug. Just an annoying behaviour :(

Comment: It is an artifact of left join and nulls being actual values and not "nothing"

Answer (score 4):

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24277843/4611564) (sorry, I can't seem to link to your username) but I believe I improved it a bit.

For the array version we can

1. get rid of the redundant double select
2. use [json_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-aggregate.html) instead of the `array_to_json(array_agg())` calls

and get this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.json_clean_array(p_data JSON)
  RETURNS JSON
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE
AS $$
-- removes elements that are json null (not sql-null) or empty
SELECT json_agg(value)
  FROM json_array_elements(p_data)
 WHERE value::text <> 'null' AND value::text <> '""';
$$;
```

For 9.3, for the object version, we can:

1. get rid of the non-used `WITH` clause
2. get rid of the redundant double select

and get this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.json_clean(p_data JSON)
  RETURNS JSON
  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE
AS $$
-- removes elements that are json null (not sql-null) or empty
  SELECT ('{' || string_agg(to_json(key) || ':' || value, ',') || '}') :: JSON
    FROM json_each(p_data)
   WHERE value::TEXT <> 'null' AND value::TEXT <> '""';
$$;
```

For 9.4, we don't have to use the string assembly stuff to build the object, as we can use the newly added [json_object_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.json_clean(p_data JSON)
  RETURNS JSON
  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE
AS $$
-- removes elements that are json null (not sql-null) or empty
  SELECT json_object_agg(key, value)
    FROM json_each(p_data)
   WHERE value::TEXT <> 'null' AND value::TEXT <> '""';
$$;
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit different but might be helpful for others:

If all objects in the array are of same structure (e.g. because you use `jsonb_build_object` to create them) you can define a "NULL object with the same structure" to use in `array_remove`:

```
...
array_remove(
    array_agg(jsonb_build_object('att1', column1, 'att2', column2)), 
    to_jsonb('{"att1":null, "att2":null}'::json)
)
...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Dont understand why this was not accepted, the answer is straightforward, valid and pretty much did the trick. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Probably less performant than Roman Pekar's solution, but a bit neater:

```
select
c.id, c.name,
array_to_json(array(select email from emails e where e.user_id=c.id))
from contacts c
```

Answer (score 1):

I made my own function for filtering json arrays:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.json_clean_array(data JSON)
  RETURNS JSON
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT
  array_to_json(array_agg(value)) :: JSON
FROM (
       SELECT
         value
       FROM json_array_elements(data)
       WHERE cast(value AS TEXT) != 'null' AND cast(value AS TEXT) != ''
     ) t;
$$;
```

I use it as

```
select 
    friend_id as friend, 
    json_clean_array(array_to_json(array_agg(comment))) as comments 
from some_entity_that_might_have_comments 
group by friend_id;
```

of course only works in postgresql 9.3. I also have a similar one for object fields:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.json_clean(data JSON)
  RETURNS JSON
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT
  ('{' || string_agg(to_json(key) || ':' || value, ',') || '}') :: JSON
FROM (
       WITH to_clean AS (
           SELECT
             *
           FROM json_each(data)
       )
       SELECT
         *
       FROM json_each(data)
       WHERE cast(value AS TEXT) != 'null' AND cast(value AS TEXT) != ''
     ) t;
$$;
```

EDIT: You can see a few utils (a few are not originally mine but they were take from other stackoverflow solutions) here at my gist:
https://gist.github.com/le-doude/8b0e89d71a32efd21283

Answer (score 0):

This way works, but there's gotta be a better way :(

```
SELECT C.id, C.name, 
  case when exists (select true from emails where user_id=C.id) then json_agg(E) else '[]' end
FROM contacts C
LEFT JOIN emails E ON C.id = E.user_id
GROUP BY C.id, C.name;
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ddefb/16

Answer (score 0):

At the time this question was asked, the following example might not have been as efficient of a choice, due to the nature of how the `email_list` would basically not limit itself based on the outer query, but newer versions of postgres handle this much better (also, I'd recommend `jsonb` over `json`)

```
WITH email_list (user_id, emails) as (
  SELECT user_id, json_agg(emails) FROM emails GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT C.id, C.name, COALESCE(E.emails, '[]'::json) as emails 
FROM contacts C LEFT JOIN email_list E ON C.id = E.user_id;
```

The `COALESCE` is only needed if you actually do want to have an empty array, otherwise the entire value would be `null`, which can be preferable output in some languages.

Answer (score 0):

In 16+ you can use `json_agg_strict` or `jsonb_agg_strict` functions.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work if you're using `json_build_object` to select multiple columns.