# GraphQL and PostgreSQL: non-nullable subfield causes "Cannot return null for non-nullable field" error

Tags: typescript, postgresql, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I have three `type-graphql` objects (and `typeorm` entities): `Entry` (dictionary headwords), `Meaning` (meanings of headwords) and `Pronunciation` (transcriptions of headwords).

There's a many-to-many relationship between `Entry` and `Meaning`, and one-to-many between `Entry` and `Pronunciation`.

I have the GraphQL query `searchEntries` which takes a query and returns matching `Entry` objects with linked `Meaning` and `Pronunciation` objects.

In my `Entry.ts` file, I defined the relationships of `Entry` like this (`@Field()` comes from `type-graphql`):

```
  @Field(() => [Pronunciation], { nullable: "itemsAndList" })
  @OneToMany(() => Pronunciation, (pronunciation) => pronunciation.entry, {
    nullable: true,
  })
  pronunciations: Relation<Pronunciation[]> | undefined;

  @Field(() => [Meaning], { nullable: "itemsAndList" })
  @ManyToMany(() => Meaning, (meaning) => meaning.entries, { nullable: true })
  meanings: Relation<Meaning[]> | undefined;
```

So, as you can see, GraphQL should know that fields `pronunciations` and `meanings` of `Entry` are nullable.

However, I'm getting this error (from `graphql`):

```
Cannot return null for non-nullable field Pronunciation.id.
```

I notice that children elements of `pronunciations` and `meanings` are still non-nullable:
[image]
[image]

Why doesn't GraphQL infer that if the parent element is nullable, its children are nullable as well?

Additional info: I'm fetching the data using `typeorm`'s raw SQL query, and the printed result looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 86,
    headword: 'lightning',
    createdAt: 2023-02-17T07:12:27.825Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-02-17T07:12:27.825Z,
    meanings: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    pronunciations: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

(I'm using `JSON_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT())` for arrays of meanings and pronunciations, and left joins for joining tables.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Update: the issue was in my raw SQL query with `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT()` that returns fields like this: `[{ id: null, transcription: null, notes: null, userId: null },...]` instead of returning a null object. Searching for a workaround

Comment: Querying for the `id` of `Pronunciation` returns `null`; where in your schema is specified that it cannot be.

Comment: You have discovered the issue :)
Post the answer to your own question :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not in GraphQL, but in PostgreSQL's `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT()` (which I used in the raw SQL query). (So really, this is a question about PostgreSQL — I will add it to the question title.)

When used with `LEFT JOIN`, `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT()` returns an object like this `{ id: null, transcription: null, notes: null, userId: null }`. `JSON_AGG()` produces an array of these objects, and GraphQL thinks `meanings` and `pronunciations` exist, throwing an error trying to access these `null` fields.

So we need to modify the query. What really helped me was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33153530/13141998) by Mike Stankavich. Using `COALESCE` and `FILTER`, the new aggregation looks like this:

```
SELECT e.*,
  COALESCE(
    JSON_AGG(m.*)
    FILTER (WHERE m.id IS NOT NULL),
    '[]'
  ) meanings,
  COALESCE(
    JSON_AGG(p.*)
    FILTER (WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL),
    '[]'
  ) pronunciations
...
```

`COALESCE` returns the first argument that is not null, so it's either the JSON array or `[]`. For `JSON_AGG()`, which builds the JSON array, `FILTER`, as Mike wrote, "prevents the aggregate from processing the rows that are null because the left join condition is not met, so you end up with a database null instead of the json [null]."

The GraphQL response for an entry that has `meanings` but no `pronunciations` looks something like this:

```
"searchEntries": [
  {
    "id": 86,
    "headword": "lightning",
    "pronunciations": [],
    "meanings": [
      {
        "id": 59,
        "definition": "a giant spark of electricity in the atmosphere between clouds, the air, or the ground"
      },
      ...]
  }
```